# kibana.dev.yml is not applied in kibana development mode

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I appreciate if someone can help me out with this issuse.

I am starting a development  for kibana plugin and installed all necessary packages.

My environment is below.

kibana 5.0.0 alpha5 (Used git clone from the git repository)

I want to start the devlopment server other than **127.0.0.1:5601**
so I have created **config/kibana.dev.yml** as below

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# This setting specifies the IP address of the back end server.
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

However, this seems not to be applied when I start the kibana server from `npm start`. It keeps starting at **127.0.0.1:5601**

Do I need any other setting to read config/kibana.dev.yml?

Thanks,
Yu Watanabe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When started in dev mode, SSL is on be default. In that configuration and if no custom certificates have been specified, the `server.host` setting has no effect and is forced to `localhost` (to match the host name in the default provided certificates) as can be seen in the [`cli/serve/serve.js`](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/cli/serve/serve.js#L36-L44) file:

```
  if (opts.dev) {
    set('env', 'development');
    set('optimize.lazy', true);
    if (opts.ssl && !has('server.ssl.cert') && !has('server.ssl.key')) {
      set('server.host', 'localhost');
      set('server.ssl.cert', fromRoot('test/dev_certs/server.crt'));
      set('server.ssl.key', fromRoot('test/dev_certs/server.key'));
    }
  }
```

You can start Kibana by specifying the `--no-ssl` switch in order for the `server.host` setting to be taken into account:

```
sh ./bin/kibana --dev --no-ssl
```

Comment: Hello Val. Thank you for the comment. Per your advice , I was able to start kibana on 0.0.0.0 by setting --no-ssl in the command line. npm start -- --no-ssl.